# R knitr html file picture locations when compiling through RStudio

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

When I make my knitr document, I see the html file in my directory. I load the file and it looks great.

However, I'm curious where the pictures are:

It gives me locations like:

```
img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACQAAAAYACAYAAAAjFnetAAAEJGlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAOBGFVd9v21QUPolvUqQWPyBYR4eKxa9VU1u5GxqtxgZJk6XtShal6dgqJOQ6N4mpGwfb6baqT3uBNwb8AUDZAw9IPCENBmJ72fbAtElThyqqSUh76MQ ...."
```

Where exactly is the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This IS the image directly encoded in html. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

see f.e. this stack overflow question: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

kind greetings

Comment: Hm, so what you're saying is that very long string actually IS the image just hard coded in text format? Pretty neat!

Comment: @user1357015 Yes, you can encode an image file as a (usually very long) character string. Please read the links in the answer.